# using define statement in PL/SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper, psql

This is one of the tasks from my homework assignement:

```
DEFINE countryid = CA
DECLARE 
country_record countries%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  INTO country_record
  FROM countries
  WHERE country_id = '&countryid';
END;
```

According to the task requirements **countryid should be declared using define statement and should be given default value CA**, then select should be performed based on value entered by the user.
When I run script i get 4 errors, *when I comment out DEFINE countryid = CA
scripts executes successfuly.*
**My question:** is define statement availiable in PL/SQL Developer?
 If it is, what I am doing wrong and could you suggest a proper usage?

edit: I get the following errors:

```
ORA-06550 row 3 column 8
PLS-00201 identificator 'COUNTRY_RECORD' have to be declared
ORA-06550 row 4 column 3
PL/SQL ORA-00904: invalid identificator
ORA-06550 row 2 column 3
PL/SQL SQL statement ignored
```

Comment: I have added info on the errors to my initial post

Comment: Does it have to be PL/SQL-Developer? Could you use SQL*PLUS instead?

Comment: DEFINE is really the sort of thing that is used as part of a code deployment or installation, and those should always be executed through SQL*Plus.

Comment: No there aren`t any constraints on development environment. I asked about PL/SQL-Devaloper because I work with it at home and on our practice at the university we use SQLplus

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DEFINE is a SQLPLUS thing, and as such isn't supported in PLSQL Developer apart from in the COMMAND window. for the sql / test window, just remove it (it will see the & and give you a popup for you to define it that way).

Answer (score 0):

in PLSQL Developer, you can use this code, But use the **Command Window**.

DEFINE countryid = 'CA'
DECLARE 
country_record countries%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  INTO country_record
  FROM countries
  WHERE country_id = '&countryid';
END;

Answer (score 0):

```
DEFINE countryid = CA
DECLARE 
country_record countries%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  INTO country_record
  FROM countries
  WHERE country_id = :countryid;
END;
```